# Why shave a cropped-frame fisheye lens instead of buying a full-frame one?

Tags: full-frame, fisheye

Recently I found [people shaving the lens hood off their Nikkor 10.5mm Fisheye](http://www.danharperphotography.com/fisheye_mod.html) which is a DX  lens to use it on a full-frame Nikon DSLR. The result is a wider field-of-view but not even completely circular, more like a wheel-barrel.

What are the advantages of this? Why not just buy a [Nikon-mount Sigma 8mm Circular fisheye](http://www.neocamera.com/lens/sigma/8mm_f3.5_ex_dg_circular_fisheye/nikon) instead? Or just get a [rectangular full-frame fisheye](http://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php?mount=nikon&crop=1&fisheye=1&by=feature&focalwide=15:min)? Has anyone seen how panorama software angle these types of images?

The lens warranty goes void and the damaging is permanent.

Comment: I do not shoot FF, but for example the Samyang 8mm fisheye is APS-C/DX only. But because of the price and quality, the FF users often decide to buy it and shave the hood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently Nikon currently only offers [a 16mm fisheye](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Camera-Lenses/All-Lenses/index.page#!/tag:IFw:Fisheye) for the FX cameras. I suppose "gaining" 5.5mm and "saving" $150 by modifying the DX is more than enough justification for some people.

Comment: That is a full-frame fisheye (180-degree FOV diagonally) but the Sigma 8mm is fully circular (180-degree FOV in any direction), so both extremes are available without modifications. So that's left is the $150, it could be.

Comment: @Itai - I would never underestimate the brand devotion of any particular segment of society, and that includes photographers. I'm sure there are people out there who would rather shave a Nikkor than "defile" their kit bag with a Sigma lens. ;-)

Answer (score 12):

The [original link](http://www.danharperphotography.com/fisheye_mod.html) is actually my article and lens.

I shaved the petals off the lens because I didn't want them to show up in the full frame camera images. Although I already have the 16mm fisheye, the 10mm shaved is a totally different look and although you don't get a full circle, it's better than spending more money for a new lens.

I wasn't concerned about warranty as I'd already had the lens past the warranty point and since moving to full frame cameras, would have sold this lens anyway.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your obviously knowledgeable insight :)

Comment: @Dan Harper - **citation needed**. You cannot quote yourself. We need a reliable source! (totally, 100% kidding!) :-)

Answer (score 0):

You've actually stated the answer in your question: **it's the wider field of view that's yielded** when you mount a smaller-format full-frame fisheye onto a larger format and shave the hood so that it no longer impinges on the frame.

There's less distortion, better sharpness and chromatic aberration control on a diagonal fisheye than with a circular. And sometimes they're cheaper (e.g., a Samyang manual fisheye lens can be $250 vs. $600 for said Sigma 8mm).

And the view coverage is crucial when shooting 360x180 spherical panos, because it can cut the required number of member images down to something easily handholdable.

With my Samyang 7.5mm for micro four-thirds on my DMC-G3, I only have 135° coverage. To cover the sphere, I have to rotate the camera in yaw at 60° intervals to take six shots around, AND a zenith (straight up) and nadir (straight down).  If I were better at judging slight angles, I could tilt the camera up 15° for the around shots, and then only need to take a nadir. But I kind of suck at judging the 60° accurately (I've shot a lot of handheld panos with holes with this combo).  Generally, I pull out the tripod and panohead instead of the plumbline.

By contrast, a NEX or Fuji X user who buys the mft 7.5 and an adapter ring, and then removes or shaves the hood, can cover the same scene with four shots rotated around at 90° intervals, just as I do with the Sigma 8mm circular on a 5DMkII. *Much* easier to train yourself to do.